# Mute sound before / after suspeding

Tags: sound, suspend, script

I find it annoying when I forget to stop videos before closing my laptop and then having sound played when opening it in public.

I tried to add a script to /lib/systemd/system-sleep:

```
#!/bin/bash

amixer -q -D pulse sset Master mute

echo 2 >> /home/user/test
```

The script seems to be called when suspending as new lines are being appended to the "test" file (twice - which might indicate that the script also runs on resume - can someone confirm this assumption?)

Either the sound system re-enables itself automatically or something else is wrong. But the amixer command executed manually works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tested your script and I have the same results. It executes twice - I did `echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')` and I have in the log file the time of suspend and the time of resume also. Testing manually the script on terminal - it do mute the sound, but after suspend/resume the sound is not muted. My guess was that the os automaticaly enables the sound on resume but if I mute the sound before going into suspend, after resume it is muted also. Adding a `sleep 1` function do not help...

Comment: Yes that was what I found out, too :(